In firefox dropzone errors with "image corrupt or truncated"
Can someone please tell me why the following code would work in Chrome but not Firefox? I believe I've implemented a fairly typical setup of Dropzone but am getting the error "Image corrupt or Truncated".
var photo = new Dropzone('#'+$(elem).attr('id'),config);

if (typeof existingFile !== 'undefined' && existingFile !== false){
    if (existingFile.indexOf(',')){
        var files = existingFile.split(',');

        for (i = 0;i<files.length;i++){
            addImages(photo,files[i],false);
        }
    } else {
        addImages(photo,existingFile,false);
    }
}

// There may be multiple images per elevation!
function addImages(photo,file,readonly){
    var p = file.split('|');

    var url = base_url+'portal/outputProof/'+p[0];

    if (readonly || typeof readonly == 'undefined'){
        $(photo).append('<img src="'+url+'" class="cursor non-dz-preview" />');
    } else {
        $('.rounded-circle.large i').addClass('d-none');

        var mockFile = {name: p[1]};

        photo.displayExistingFile(mockFile,url);
        photo.files.push(mockFile);
    }
}

The line that is triggering the problem is $(photo).append('<img src="'+url+'" class="cursor non-dz-preview" />');. I've tried doing pre-loading using new Image() but this was unsuccessful and have tried ChatGTP but that couldn't also answer my problem!
